# Java code to add data in access database is not working properly

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc

I'm trying this code to add the data into the access database. It is not showing any error and the code is running successfully but the values are not being updated to the database.

Code:

```
String BS = null,DH = null,DL = null,PHV = null,AL = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        String Data_Input="OK DATA BS:10.1 AL:10.2 PHV:10.3 DH:10.4 DL:10.5";
        System.out.println("Original String as Data Input :"+Data_Input);
        Connection con;
       PreparedStatement st = null;

        //code to divide the string into substring

        try{
            String BS = null,DH = null,DL = null,PHV = null,AL = null;
            String[] ArrString=Data_Input.split("\\s+");
              for(int i=0;i<ArrString.length;i++){

                  String test=ArrString[i].toString();

                  //Testing Code

                  String[] Split_Data=test.split(":");
                  for(int k=0;k<Split_Data.length;k++){

                      String Data=Split_Data[k].toString();

                    // System.out.print("Second Value :"+Second);

                      //System.out.println("\tAfter Second Print :");

                      if(Data.equals("BS")){
                         System.out.println("We Finally Got BS :"+Split_Data[k+1].toString());
                         BS=Split_Data[k+1].toString();
                         //st.setString(1,BS);
                     }
                      if(Data.equals("AL")){
                         System.out.println("We Finally Got AL :"+Split_Data[k+1].toString());
                         AL=Split_Data[k+1].toString();
                         // st.setString(2,AL);
                     }
                       if(Data.equals("PHV")){
                         System.out.println("We Finally Got PHV :"+Split_Data[k+1].toString());
                          PHV=Split_Data[k+1].toString();
                         // st.setString(3,PHV);
                     }
                        if(Data.equals("DH")){
                         System.out.println("We Finally Got DH :"+Split_Data[k+1].toString());
                          DH=Split_Data[k+1].toString();
                           // st.setString(4,DH);

                     }
                         if(Data.equals("DL")){
                         System.out.println("We Finally Got DL :"+Split_Data[k+1].toString());
                          DL=Split_Data[k+1].toString();
                          //st.setString(5,DL);
                         }

                  }

                  System.out.print("Substring After Break :"+test);
                  System.out.println("\tNext Value :");

             }
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              String demo="jdbc:odbc:Test";

             System.out.println("Database Initialization Succesfull");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection(demo); 
             st=con.prepareStatement("insert into Table1 values(?,?,?,?,?)");
             st.setString(1, BS);
             System.out.println("BS::"+BS);
             st.setString(2, AL);
             System.out.println("AL::"+AL);
             st.setString(3, PHV);
             System.out.println("PHV::"+PHV);
             st.setString(4, DH);
             System.out.println("DH::"+DH);
             st.setString(5, DL);
             System.out.println("DL::"+DL);
             st.executeUpdate();
```

Output:

```
Database Initialization Succesfull
BS::10.1
AL::10.2
PHV::10.3
DH::10.4
DL::10.5
Database Statements Executed Succesfully..!!!
```

But values are not updated in database

Comment: I don't see where you're doing a database commit or closing the connection to the database.

Comment: Put `System.out.println(con.getCatalog());` immediately after the `DriverManager.getConnection` call. What does it show you?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The default is auto commit, so there is no need to call commit explicitly.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You were write Buddy i forgot to put the con.close statement